# Android Transitive Dependency

Tags: android, dependencies

I have a project which has **module A**. Module A depends on **'commons.aar'** which in turn depends on **'ormlite.jar'**. My project also depends on **'ormlite.jar'**. So when I include all dependencies, I get

> "**Error: Program type already present:**"

How to resolve this?

**build.gradle of Project has following dependencies**

```
dependencies {

implementation files('libs/ormlite-android-sqlcipher-4.46.jar')
implementation files('libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar')
    implementation project(':moduleA')
}
```

**build.gradle of moduleA contains following dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')        
}
```

**build.gradle of commons  has following dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')       
    implementation files('libs/ormlite-android-sqlcipher-4.46.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ormlite-core-4.48.jar')
}
```

Comment: if i exclude ormlite from my project, I am getting compile time errors. How to avoid that ?

Comment: You are using aar file as lib? Or gradle dependencies ? Add you `build.gradle` with question.

Comment: ormlite is used as a lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by excluding the ormlite.jar from commons.aar using the following LOC

```
 compileOnly files('libs/ormlite.jar')
```

& adding to the main project.